# Symfony2 Composer and environment variables

Tags: symfony, heroku, environment-variables, composer-php, travis-ci

I would like to set the configuration of my symfony2 project using environment variables.

In the server I have defined:

```
SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER
SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD
SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME
SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST
SYMFONY__DATABASE__DRIVER
```

My parameters.yml.dist looks like this:

```
#app/config/parameters.yml.dist
parameters:
    database_host:     "%database.host%"
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     "%database.name%"
    database_user:     "%database.user%"
    database_password: "%database.password%"
    database_driver:   "%database.driver%"
```

when I run composer I get an exception

```
composer install --dev --no-interaction --prefer-source
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]                                                   
You have requested a non-existent parameter "database.driver". Did you mean one of these: "database_user", "database_driver"?
```

These variables are defined in the server so I can modify the parameters.yml.dist to define these values. But this does not seams the right way, because wat I really want to use are the environment variables.

Note: I want to read this environment variables in travis, heroku and my vagrant machine. I only want to have in the repository the vagrant machine variables.

Which is the proper way to do this? 
How should look my parameters.yml.dist?

Answer (score 3):

Looks you are doing everything okay.

Here is the complete documentation for [Setting Environment Variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html) which I believe you already read.

What is important to note is this:

> Also, in order for your console to work (which does not use Apache),
>   you must export these as shell variables. On a Unix system, you can
>   run the following:

```
$ export SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER=user
$ export SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD=secret
```

I remember once I have a similar issue, I was setting everything on APACHE, but when running commands it wasn't working because I forgot to EXPORT the variables on the system.

**Be aware that using export is a temp solution, if you reset your server those values will be lost, you will need to setup in a permanent way according to your OS.**

Comment: Thank you @Richard I have fix it exporting the variables. in /etc/profile.d/myvariables.sh

Answer (score 1):

I think you solved this long time ago, but the problem is actually that you have 2 `_` between DATABASE and USER and the parser for this have a string replace function that replaces every `__` with a `.` .

For your example to work you should have written like this:

SYMFONY__DATABASE_USER -> database_user
SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER -> database.user

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this bundle](https://github.com/Incenteev/DynamicParametersBundle) if your system version is >= 2.6.2:

> This bundle provides a way to read parameters from environment
>   variables at runtime. The value defined in the container parameter is
>   used as fallback when the environment variable is not available.

Comment: Thank you @xurshid29, but the bundle fix this problem but is not in stable version. Also set the environment variables seams a better way, more simple and I don´t need to add another dependency.